# Minecraft spawning in potions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to create a mob arena (dark) so that I can finish a mini game map. I want to put a button that will give the nearest player an extended Potion of Night Vision. What would be the code to spawn that in?

Comment: You could put them in dispensers at random checkpoints.

Comment: This is for an arena, and I need an unlimited amount because it will take a very long time for the player to win.

Comment: A Potion of Night Vision lasts for six minutes.

Comment: And? The mini game is designed for a group. It requires 64 Golden Apples, which cost 64 gold each, which require 64 gold collected, which a gold is 1 mob drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data value for [potions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion) is `373` and the "damage value" for an extended Night Vision potion is `8262`, and you want to give quantity `1`. Using these in a [command block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_block) hooked up to your button, with `@p` used to select the nearest player, looks like so:

> /give @p 373 1 8262

Assuming you want this button to work only once, you can put an [RS NOR latch](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Circuits/Latches#RS_NOR_Latch_.26_Input-Stabilizers) between the button and the command block, so that the button activates the SET input (optionally with a hidden button accessible only to you attached to the RESET input, for easy testing).

You may also want to use the `/say` command to alert the player that they just got the potion, since in the heat of the moment it's easy to overlook something quietly popping into your inventory, if your not expecting it. They'll still have to ready and drink it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do /effect @p 16 (which is night vision) 999999 (which is forever) 255 (amplifier)
you don't have to put in the parenthesis.

Comment: This does solve my problem (but does not answer the question). +1 for thinking outside the box tho.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/effect give @p night_vision 999999 255`

Answer (score 1):

As of Minecraft 1.9, potions are specified using NBT instead of cryptic numbers. Therefore, the command for giving a player an extended night vision potion is:

```
/give <player> potion{Potion:"minecraft:long_night_vision"}
```